# Getting the SocketTimeoutException when trying to connect with JIRA Java Rest API(JRJC)

Tags: java, jira-rest-java-api

Getting the SocketTimeoutException when trying to connect with JIRA Java Rest API. Please find the stack trace and sample code given below.

Sample code :-

```
JiraRestClientFactory factory = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();

URI uri = new URI("https://XXXXX.atlassian.net");

client = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(uri, "XXXXX", "XXXXX");

final Issue issue1 = client.getIssueClient().getIssue("UST-761").claim();
```

Stack trace:-

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
       at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:156)
       at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.DefaultHttpClient$3.apply(DefaultHttpClient.java:256)
       at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.DefaultHttpClient$3.apply(DefaultHttpClient.java:249)
       at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$Of$2.apply(Promises.java:276)
       at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$Of$2.apply(Promises.java:272)
       at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$2.onFailure(Promises.java:167)
       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$7.run(Futures.java:1074)
```

Caused by: 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException

```
   at org.apache.http.nio.pool.RouteSpecificPool.timeout(RouteSpecificPool.java:170)
   at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool.requestTimeout(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:403)
   at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool$InternalSessionRequestCallback.timeout(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:593)
   at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.SessionRequestImpl.timeout(SessionRequestImpl.java:180)
   at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processTimeouts(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:214)
```

Comment: Could be `HTTP/HTTPS` issue. Your Jira instance is using HTTPS and you are using `factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication()`

Comment: Thanks for you response. 

I tried with installing with SSL certificate. but that is not working for me. Is there any other way to create the JiraRestClient instead of  **factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication()**.

Comment: Isn't it possible that it is some kind of proxy issue ? Maybe try tips mentioned here https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/247245/jira-rest-java-client-https-problem . Try to connect to https://jira.atlassian.com/